# Change selected value of asp.net dropdownlist without trigging postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

How can I change the selected value of an asp.net dropdownlist without a trigging a postback?

I have tried setting the autopostback to false, but the "selected" attribute on the option don't change when selecting another option in the dropdownlist.

I've seen some examples using an updatepanel and I've tried this with success, but due to other javascript and jquery functions on the page I can't use this without having a lot of trouble with other functions..

**CODE UPDATE**

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="USERS" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" runat="server"
                     Width="150px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It's default nature is to not postback...  I'm not sure why you are experiencing a problem because I've used them with no side effects.  Can you post the markup?

Comment: Is your EnableViewState property set to true? Are you avoiding to repopulate the dropdown before trying to read the selected item (using a condition on !IsPostback for example)?

Comment: As you can see I have posted my dropdownlist markup above. When I change the value in the dropdownlist I and inspect the element, it's still the first item that has the "selected" property..

Answer (score 0):

Try AJAX with asp:UpdatePanel and asp:updateprogress tags. And if you have already tried this, show us your code, so that we can help.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I cant use updatepanel because its making a lot of other problems when jquery is used..

Comment: It wont affect other jQuery , specify the ID attribute properly.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme Explain you in detail...

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
     </ContentTemplate>
```

and add update progress if you want

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpProDisp" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" OnLoad="UpdatePanelProdDisp_Load">
          <ProgressTemplate>
          </ProgressTemplate>
 </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

also add Modal pop up

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpProDisp" PopupControlID="Panel1" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalExtender">
     <img alt="Processing" src="../Images/Processing.jpg" />
       <br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblProcessing" runat="server" Text="Processing..." CssClass="TitleBar"></asp:Label>
  </asp:Panel>
```

with following javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(showPopup);
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(hidePopup);

function showPopup(sender, args) {
var ModalControl = '<%= modalExtender.ClientID %>';
$find(ModalControl).show();
}

function hidePopup(sender, args) {
var ModalControl = '<%= modalExtender.ClientID %>';
$find(ModalControl).hide();
} 
</script>
```

tell me if it worked.